# Multi-select statement in Rails but trying to prevent duplicate queries for a specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am building a Web API for a legacy database and there are some duplicate ids that I need to prevent from being queried.

An example of the duplicates look like this:

```
FIRST LAST: [
[
"1213.21",
"HHLOG",
"2020-09-18T14:43:00.000-05:00",
"121748.0"
],
[
"1213.21",
"HHLOG",
"2020-09-18T16:30:00.000-05:00",
"121748.0"
]
],
```

The `"121748.0"` is actually the `pb_id` you'll see below in the `select` statement.  These are the type of duplicates I am looking to remove.

Here is my current select statement:

```
@nova_loads = OpsHeader
    .select(:pb_id, :pb_net_rev, :pb_bill_id, :pb_id, :pb_dt_canc)
```

I have tried a few different things to see if would work:

```
@nova_loads = OpsHeader
    .select((Distinct(pb_id), :pb_net_rev, :pb_bill_id, :pb_id, :pb_dt_canc)
```

```
@nova_loads = OpsHeader
    .select(:pb_id, :pb_net_rev, :pb_bill_id, :pb_id, :pb_dt_canc).distinct
```

and a plethora of others.  None of them are working and I am little confused as to why.

What do I need to do to have a multi-select statement that can filter off duplicates based off of a certain key value.  In this scenario, I will always want the first record of the two.  The next record is always the duplicate, so that makes it a little easier... just not for me :D.

EDIT - Here is my full query:

```
    @nova_loads = OpsHeader
    .select(:pb_id, :pb_net_rev, :pb_bill_id, :pb_id, :pb_dt_canc)
    .where('pb_net_rev > ?', 0.0)
    .where(pb_dt_canc: nil)
    .joins(ops_stop_rec: :driver_header)
    .select(:ops_driver1, :dh_first_name, :dh_last_name, :ops_delivered_time)
    .where(:ops_stop_rec => {ops_delivered_time: '2020-09-18 00:00:00' .. '2020-09-18 24:00:00'}).find_each(batch_size: 1000) do |loads, i|
          @load_objects.push(loads.dh_first_name + ' ' + loads.dh_last_name => [loads.pb_net_rev, loads.pb_bill_id, loads.ops_delivered_time, loads.pb_id])
    end
```

Comment: Did you try to use `.group` method ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [distinct_on](https://apidock.com/rails/Arel/SelectManager/distinct_on) for this. Not fully documented, so might break some time in the future, but here goes:

```
OpsHeader.select(:pb_id, :pb_net_rev, :pb_bill_id, :pb_id, :pb_dt_canc).tap do |rel|
  rel.arel.distinct_on(OpsHeader.arel_table[:pb_id])
end
```

Also `distinct_on` currently only works on postgres.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for my exact query... :?

Comment: The minimal example I gave works right? Start adding elements of your query step-by-step and see when it breaks. Do note that the distinct_on definitely has to be after all `.select`-s and generally, later is better. Also it only works on postgres as of now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an old Firebird database.  ````distinct_on```` is not compatible with it.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the postgres dependenency. Sad I couldn't help.

Comment: All good!  Thanks for giving it ago.  I've had a hard time trying to find good literature on Firebird/Rails integration.  Given that FB databases have fallen out of favor over the last decade and a half, it seems like helpful info is scarce.